# Resizable row/column headers in NatTable

Tags: swt, nattable, nebula

I have NatTable with column and row headers, and use CornerLayer for it. How to make row and column headers resizable like any other column or row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the necessary bindings to the header regions

```
gridLayer.addConfiguration(new AbstractUiBindingConfiguration() {

    @Override
    public void configureUiBindings(UiBindingRegistry uiBindingRegistry) {
        uiBindingRegistry.registerFirstMouseMoveBinding(
                new ColumnResizeEventMatcher(SWT.NONE, GridRegion.ROW_HEADER, 0),
                new ColumnResizeCursorAction());

        uiBindingRegistry.registerFirstMouseDragMode(
                new ColumnResizeEventMatcher(SWT.NONE, GridRegion.ROW_HEADER, 1),
                new ColumnResizeDragMode());

        uiBindingRegistry.registerFirstMouseMoveBinding(
                new RowResizeEventMatcher(SWT.NONE, GridRegion.COLUMN_HEADER, 0),
                new RowResizeCursorAction());

        uiBindingRegistry.registerFirstMouseDragMode(
                new RowResizeEventMatcher(SWT.NONE, GridRegion.COLUMN_HEADER, 1),
                new RowResizeDragMode());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. One note: I've also registered these bindings to GridRegion.CORNER, so that it can be resize also from corner region