# changing the height of column header in Nattable

Tags: java, swt, nattable

I'm developing an swt application, in which Nattable is used to display the data read from CSV files. However, the column headers are not displayed completely (see the figure below).

[image: an example Nattable grid]

What is the easiest way to change the height of column headers programmatically, and also make it resizable by user?

Comment: Please provide some code or a [mcve] which recreates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the column header row height programmatically either by using API on the `DataLayer` of the column header or use the `RowResizeCommand`

```
natTable.doCommand(new RowResizeCommand(natTable, 0, 0));
```

Make it resizable by the user, add the necessary configuration as explained here: [Resizable row/column headers in NatTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38637088/resizable-row-column-headers-in-nattable/38654000#38654000)

Comment: Not sure how you use it and how your setup looks like, but with the default configuration it works. The shown snippet resizes the column header row to 0 which makes it disappear.

Comment: The third command parameter is the height to set. So provide an appropriate value...