# Change height of the Column Header, not resize, in Nattable

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, nattable

I want to increase the size of the column header cell so I have made a CustomCellPainter extending BeveledBorderDecorator class and I have assigned interiorBounds.height as 25 as shown below, but the content from the columnHeaderLayer was getting hidden behind the bodyLayer, just like image provided here [changing the height of column header in Nattable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921750/changing-the-height-of-column-header-in-nattable).

```
public void paintCell(ILayerCell cell, GC gc, Rectangle adjustedCellBounds, IConfigRegistry configRegistry) {
            Rectangle interiorBounds = getWrappedPainterBounds(cell, gc,
                    adjustedCellBounds, configRegistry);
            
            interiorBounds.height = 25;
            
            super.paintCell(cell, gc, interiorBounds, configRegistry);
```

I want to change the height of column header cell and want it to reflect properly at the time of rendering. I would like to know what API to be used for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never touch a painter unless you know what you are doing.

If you want to change the height of the `ColumnHeaderLayer` programmatically while setting up the structure, you simply need to configure the `DataLayer` accordingly.

```
ILayer columnHeaderLayer = new ColumnHeaderLayer(
    new DataLayer(columnHeaderDataProvider, DataLayer.DEFAULT_COLUMN_WIDTH, 25),
    viewportLayer,
    selectionLayer);
```